# Using Enthought

Tags: python, scipy

I need to calculate the inverse of the complementary error function (erfc^(1)) for a problem.

I was looking into Python tools for it, and many threads said Enthought has most of the
math tools needed, so I downloaded and installed it in my local user account. But I am not
very sure about how to use it?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

[SciPy](http://scipy.org/), which is included in the [Enthought](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthought) Python distribution, contains that [special function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.erfcinv.html#scipy.special.erfcinv).

```
In [1]: from scipy.special import erfcinv
In [2]: from numpy import linspace
In [3]: x = linspace(0, 1, 10)
In [4]: y = erfcinv(x)
In [5]: y
Out[5]: 
array([  1.27116101e+308,   1.12657583e+000,   8.63123068e-001,
         6.84070350e-001,   5.40731396e-001,   4.16808192e-001,
         3.04570194e-001,   1.99556951e-001,   9.87900997e-002,
         0.00000000e+000])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of calculations in the Enthought Python Distribution (EPD) with the inverse of the complementary error function (`erfcinv`), which is included in the [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) package that comes with the EPD:

```
C:\>c:\Python25\python
EPD Py25 (4.1.30101) -- http://www.enthought.com/epd

Python 2.5.2 |EPD Py25 4.1.30101| (r252:60911, Dec 19 2008, 13:49:12) [MSC v.131
0 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from scipy.special import erfcinv
>>> erfcinv(0.)
1.271161006153646e+308
>>> erfcinv(1.)
0.0
>>> erfcinv(2.)
-1.271161006153646e+308
>>> exit()

C:\>
```